# Не отображается закрытый член класса в описании дружественной функции

Tags: c++, ооп

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Столкнулся с проблемой: есть класс Вектор в нем содержится перегруженный оператор << для сцепленного вывода Вектора в программе. В описании класса данный метод объявлен другом класса. В сpp файле описания методов класса Вектор закрытые поля класса недоступны дружественной функции(( Как быть?

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&out, const Vector&v);
```

В Vector.cpp пытаюсь описать метод:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Vector&v)
{
    if (v.size == 0); //тут не могу получить доступ к закрытому полю size
}


 /*Описание класса Вектор*/
#pragma once
const int MAX_SIZE = 20; //максимальный размер вектора

class Vector 
{
    int size; //текущий размер
    int* begin; //указатель на начало дин. массива
public:
    //конструктор без параметров
    Vector() { size = 0; begin = 0;}
    //конструктор c параметром
    Vector(int s);
    //конструктор с параметрами
    Vector(int s, int* mas);
    //конструктор копирования
    Vector(Vector& v);
    //деструктор
    ~Vector();
    //перегрузка оператора присваивания
    const Vector& operator= (const Vector& v);
    //перегрузка квадратных скобок
    int operator[](Vector& v);
    //добавление элемента в Вектор
    Vector operator+(int a);
    //удаление элемента из Вектора
    Vector operator--();
    /*дружественные функции которые осуществляют
    возможность сцепленных вызовов*/
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&out, const Vector&v);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Vector&v);
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы что-то недоговариваете или выдумываете. Не надо выдумывать. Приводите реальный код, а не эти огрызки.

Comment: Привел реальный код описания класса. Класс не шаблонный

Comment: Все прекрасно компилирутеся: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5658a599e4b083e. Вы что-то недоговариваете.

Comment: Я добавил скрин

Comment: Не понял. Вы что ли жалуетесь на то, что в "GUI списочке" это поле не вываливается? Ну так впишите его ручками, без "GUI списочка". Вы написали, что "не можете получить доступ". Это значит, что вы получаете **сообщение об ошибке компилятора**. Вы получаете сообщение об ошибке компилятора или нет?

Comment: ну второй скрин считается ошибкой компилятора?

Comment: Нет, не считается. Это сообщение IntelliSense. Сообщения IntelliSense - это не "ошибки". Вы пробовали **компилировать** свой код? Что сказал компилятор?

Comment: https://rextester.com/OCYB2140 - убедитесь, что все компилируется...